# How to define static variables in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I want to define an array with a constant value
e.g. `const arr = ["a", "b"];`. However, the compiler will think it's `string[]`. Is there is a way to make it a constant type as is so the type of arr should be `["a", "b"]`. The only way I found was to do like: `const arr: ["a", "b"] = ["a", "b"];`. but it's like code duplication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define it as a read-only constant. Keep in mind that a constant can never be reassigned anyways.

```
const CHOICES = ['a', 'b'] as const;
```